# How to close the current tab of the browser in protractor with out closing the complete browser

Tags: protractor

In the application i have two options "Google , Twitter" . When i click on any option it will open in new tab.

In my test case , i would like to click on google or twitter option and close the google or twitter tab and return back to the my application.

Is there any way to close only newly opened tab.

I tried below solutions.

`browser.close();` is closing the entire browser.

Can any one help me how to close only tab of the browser ( in my case google tab or twitter tab) with out closing the entire browser in protractor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following:

Switch to the new opened tab. Close the current windows (in this case, the new tab). Switch back to the first window.

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((handles) => {
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    browser.driver.close();
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used it in one project.

```
    const allWindowHandlers = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();

        if (allWindowHandlers.length > 1) {
          for (let windowHandlerIndex = 1; windowHandlerIndex < allWindowHandlers.length; windowHandlerIndex++) {
            const windowHandler = allWindowHandlers[windowHandlerIndex];
            await browser.switchTo().window(windowHandler);
            await browser.close();
          }
        }

    await browser.switchTo().window(allWindowHandlers[0]);
```

You can use it inside your steps implementation.

You can use it before starting a new scenario, to be sure that only the first window is selected and everything else is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I did and this and it works for me :

```
  browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
  let newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
  browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
    browser.close();
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
  });
});
```