# Protractor Test fails when Opening PDF file in new Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

On our app, when we click on a button, it is opening a PDF file in a new browser tab. I am trying to validate that the URL is opened correctly, so I wrote the code following the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577637/how-to-close-the-current-tab-of-the-browser-in-protractor-with-out-closing-the-c?rq=1):

```html
G.View_Doc_Button.click();
      browser.sleep(2000);
      browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
         console.log(handles);
         let newWindowHandle = handles[1]; 
         browser.driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {

            browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(Tab){
               expect(Tab).toBe('localhost:10001/assets/Doc.pdf');

            });
            browser.close();
            browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
         });
         // browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);


         // browser.driver.close();

         // browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);

      });
```

The code fails on these lines :

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(Tab){
           expect(Tab).toBe('localhost:10001/assets/Doc.pdf');

        });
```

Since the tab opens a PDF document, most probably it is resulting in the failure. the error is

> " AfterAll Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the
>   page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are
>   undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or
>   becaus e your test involves client-side navigation, which can
>   interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643
>   for details""

Please note that, If I remove the URL validation part, the code works fine. but it beats my purpose.

How can this be solved?

Comment: You probably need to turn off angular synchronization via [waitForAngularEnabled](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511013/non-angular-page-opened-after-a-click

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm !!